# Separable Hamiltonian method in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian

When using the 'method' of separable Hamiltonians, do the parts into which the Hamiltonian is decomposed have to commute?

For example, if $H=H_1+H_2$ and the Hamiltonian is separable, its eigenvalues are given by the sum of the eigenvalues of the individual Hamiltonians, but do the two Hamiltonians have to commute in order to do so?

Comment: $H_1$ would depend on $x_1$ and $p_1$ only, whereas $H_2$ would depend on $x_2$ and $p_2$ only, so indeed they would commute.

Comment: Are $H_1$ and $H_2$ supposed to be represent Hamiltonians for different particles or different degrees of freedom, then they automatically commute.  If not, then they must commute in order for separation to work, because otherwise, they don't share an eigenbasis, and so you can't construct a full eigenbasis for the space as a set of products of eigenstates of the individual Hamiltonians.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Therefore the fact that the two Hamiltonians commute is a direct consequence of the fact that the total Hamiltonian is separable, because this means that H_1 and H_2 refer to different degrees of freedom and therefore they commute?

Comment: It’s more the other way around.  If there is no coupling, the degrees of freedom are completely independent and so they will commute.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero By "coupling" you mean that there's no interaction between the Hamiltonians?

Comment: no coupling means no interactions between the systems.